# Как передать по значение из SQlite на другой Activity?

Tags: java, android

Как передать 1 значение на другое Activity, если я вывожу весь SQLite в ListView.

```
                String[] from = new String[]{DBHelper.KEY_NAME, DBHelper.KEY_TEXT};
                int[] to = new int[]{R.id.name, R.id.email};
                SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_item, cursor, from, to, 0);



    }



    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick (ListView l, View v, int position, long id){

        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

                intent = new Intent(diskont.this, xutt.class); //Заполняем Intent
                intent.putExtra("hello", R.id.email);

        startActivity(intent); 
    }
```

Но выводиться, не текст который в SQLite, а число(Скорее всего ID элемента)

Comment: так вы передаете строковый id R.id.email. передавайте то, что хотите.

Comment: Как мне передать текст из DBHelper.KEY_TEXT

Comment: У вас есть `position`, есть ListView, есть adapter, получайте нужное значение и в интент его.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1275954/11515